# How do I change a value of a BooleanField in Django?

Tags: python, django

The view class:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
```

The model class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    neg_sentiment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm trying to get BooleanField to change to True, but I don't know how to reassign it

Comment: What happens when you try: `post.neg_sentiment = True` and `post.save()` in your `post_publish` function?

Comment: @DanielSokol same results, it doesn't change

Comment: what is calling the `post_publish` function?

Comment: @DanielSokol huh strange, there's nothing calling it which means that the function is useless. Turns out it's all being done by a CreateView.

Comment: @DanielSokol here comes another question, how am I supposed to change the BooleanField now?

Comment: I think your old approach was correct - all you need to do is send a post request from the front end to a url - then route the url to your view function that you defined before

Comment: why not use the django admin site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('publish_post/<int:pk>', views.PublishPost, name='publish_post'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def PublishPost(request, pk):

    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.neg_sentiment.save()
    post.save()

    context = {'success' : True}

    return HttpResponse(context)
```

Then in your template you can set up a post request to 'publish_post' with the id of the post object.